# In drupal 7, what does make a menu link a stale item?

Tags: caching, navigation

I'm creating menu links with this kind of code:

```
$item = array(
  'link_path' => drupal_get_normal_path('link-path'),
  'link_title' => 'link-title',
  'menu_name' => 'menu-name',
  'weight' => 0,
  'expanded' => 1,
);

// Look the table first if the data does exist
$menuId = db_query("SELECT mlid from {menu_links} WHERE link_title=:link_title AND link_path=:link_path", array(':link_title' =>  
$link['link_title'], ':link_path' => $link['link_path']))->fetchField();
if ($menuId === FALSE) {  
    $menuId = menu_link_save($item);
    echo "New entry " . $menuId . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "exists " . $menuId . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Later on, if I call any of these functions:

- `menu_rebuild()`
- `drupal_flush_all_caches()`
- Or if I clear the cache from the web ui.

All my menu links are deleted. According to the documentation, these functions "remove stale items from {menu_links}". And I am unable to find out what is missing in the parameters of `menu_link_save` or if I need an extra step. If I stop the script before flushing, the content table menu_link looks OK.

I'd like some explanations about the workflow of `menu_rebuild` that causes some objects to be deleted (i.e. is there a flag or something, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to Stale menu link static caches? https://www.drupal.org/node/2425261